# How can I have two Artifactory repositories?

Tags: artifactory

I wanna have two Artifactory repositories,one on the server that is connected to the internet and can download Artifacts,and another that doesn't have internet,and its connected to the server that have internet,and many client that are connected to the server that doesn't have internet
how can I configure them?!

Comment: "disconnected" means disconnected only from Internet or from intranet as well? Can the two instances "talk" to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the disconnected instance as a proxy to the connected one (declare it as a remote repository).

Comment: how can i use the disconnected instance as a proxy? should i use the proxy option for it?!!
please "explain" it completely.
thx

Answer (score 0):

- On the instance connected to the internet you should configure
  [remote repositories](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories) which serves as a 'proxy' to various public
  repositories you would like to use. The remote repositories will
  cache the artifacts downloaded from public repositories.
- After you have the remote repositories configured, you can aggregate them into a single [virtual repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories). You can use the 'remote-repos' repository which you should already have.
- On the disconnected instance create a remote repository pointing at the virtual repository you created on the connected instance (for example 'remote-repos')
- Clients should be configured to resolve artifacts from the instance on the disconnected server